# Syntax of Linq Query with Filter in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to filter my Linq Query so that I only receive the Items with a certain mail address. What would be the correct syntax for Filter?

The 'Mail' column in my SharePoint List is a single line of text (not an actual person field/column).

I think the documentation for this (especially LINQ) is very poor.

```
 Items = await MyGraphClient.graph.Sites["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
     .Lists["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
     .Items
     .Request()
     .Expand("fields($select=ID,Status,Mail,Datum)")
     .Filter("fields($select=Mail) eq 'test@xxxxxxxx.de'")
     .GetAsync();
```

The error I get: Could not find a property named 'Mail' on type 'microsoft.graph.listItem'

The rest of the Query works as expected.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried  `.Filter("Mail eq 'test@xxxxxxxx.de'")` ? Since the 'Mail' column is a single line of text so it may work.

Comment: Yes I also tried this. The error message stays the same: Invalid filter clause: Could not find a property named 'Mail' on type 'microsoft.graph.listItem'.

Comment: Try  `.Filter("fields/Mail eq 'test@xxxxxxxx.de'") `  If the error still occurs then you need to check the actual internal name of the 'Mail' column in the shared EndPoint List and replace that accordingly. You can see How to find internal name [here](https://sharepointstuff.com/2022/02/09/find-internal-column-name/comment-page-1/)

Comment: This is not a LINQ query.

Comment: `$expand is not currently supported with advanced queries.`, in your requirement, what you want to have should similar to `?$expand($select=ID,Status,Mail,Datum&$filter=Mail eq 'xxx')`, it so, then I'm afraid Graph API hasn't supported it yet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#query-scenarios-that-require-advanced-query-capabilities

Comment: Unfortunately `.Filter("fields/Mail eq 'test@xxxxxxxx.de'")` isn't working (with or without expand).

Comment: It's working now with `.Expand("fields($select=TicketID,Status,Mail,Datum)")
.Filter("fields/Mail eq 'test@xxxxxxxxxxx.de'")` BUT you have to add Mail as an indexed column in SharePoint. Thank you everyone!

Comment: thank you for your sharing, could you pls post your solution below as the answer so that it might help others meeting similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now with

`.Expand("fields($select=TicketID,Status,Mail,Datum)").Filter("fields/Mail eq 'test@xxxxxxxxxxx.de'")`

BUT you have to add 'Mail' as an indexed column in SharePoint. Thank you everyone!